# Method visitor is not working in Java ASM visitLineNumber()

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I want to add a method call to each line of a specific class. To do this i want to use the ASM (visitor based) library.

The not working part means the code (Method call) is not inserted.

My (not working) code in the MethodVisitor class looks like this so far:

```
@Override
public void visitLineNumber(int line, Label start) {
  mv.visitMethodInsn(
      Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC,
      classpath,
      "visitLine",
      "()V",
      false);
  super.visitLineNumber(line, start);
```

I tried another method of the MethodVisitor and it worked just fine like this:

```
@Override
public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
  mv.visitMethodInsn(
          Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC,
          classpath,
          "visitLine",
          "()V",
          false);
  super.visitInsn(opcode);
}
```

My question is: Why does the first thing not work but the second?

edit: More context:

I want to insert the method call visitLine() in every line of code. A possible example class is this one:

```
public class Calculator {
  public int evaluate(final String pExpression) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (String summand : pExpression.split("\\+")) {
      sum += Integer.parseInt(summand);
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

becomes:

```
public class Calculator {
  public int evaluate(final String pExpression) {
    OutputWriter.visitLine();
    int sum = 0;
    OutputWriter.visitLine();
    for (String summand : pExpression.split("\\+")) {
      OutputWriter.visitLine();
      sum += Integer.parseInt(summand);
    }
    OutputWriter.visitLine();
    return sum;
  }
}
```

I have a basic setup of ClassReader, ClassWriter and ClassVisitor like this:

```
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(pClassName);
ClassVisitor tcv = new TransformClassVisitor(cw);
cr.accept(tcv, 0);
return cw.toByteArray();
```

In the MethodVisitor i only override this method:

```
@Override
  public void visitLineNumber(int line, Label start) {
    System.out.println(line);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(
            Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC,
            classpath,
            "visitLine",
            "()V",
            false);
    super.visitLineNumber(line, start);
  }
```

This prints out all the lines of the visited classes but the method call i wanted to add was not added or at least is not executed.

edit: Found out some new stuff:

The visitLineNumber insertion works if it doesn't insert something in the last line of a method.

For example the calculator class from above:
As long as there is no code inserted in line 7 (the return line) the code works fine. I tried another class with 2 return statements and it also worked fine until it reached the last return statement.

I think there is an error with the order the method call is inserted. Maybe it is inserted after the return statement which leads to an error when validating the class file.

Any new ideas on the topic?

Comment: You should be more specific on the “is not working” part. If you mean, it’s never called, recall that it can only be called, when the particular optional debug information is available.

Comment: Yeah sorry edited the text. The code i want to insert with visitMethodInsn() is not inserted. It gets called on every line i tried that one before.

Comment: When you say that `visitLineNumber` gets called, there is no recognizable error. You have to provide more context. Generally, the mapping between source code lines and bytecode instructions is not trivial and the idea of inserting statements at every line is error prone.

Comment: Ok i give more context when i get home. Is there a better way to insert a statement in every line?

Comment: Added more context. I hope you understand my Problem now.

Comment: I understand your problem as far as you described the symptoms, however, according to this description and the code you’ve shown, these symptoms should not happen unless there’s still something missing. E.g. my best bet is that you are ignoring a `VerifyError` happening when trying to use the transformed code and hence, are proceeding with the unaltered code.

Comment: Is there a way to show a verify error?

Comment: How do you use the instrumented code? Normally, it’s hard to overlook a `VerifyError` unless you catch it somewhere without reporting.

Comment: What do you mean by how do i use the code? I want to track what parts of the code are used if thats what you meant.

Comment: `cw.toByteArray()` produces a `byte[]` array. You have to turn this into an actual runtime class somehow. During this process, the JVM may throw a `VerifyError` if the byte array’s contents has an error. And also during this process, said error seems to get caught and ignored. To get a useful diagnostic, you have to change this process. Or document it here, so we can provide suggestions on how to nail the problem down.

Comment: Do you know a way to achieve this? I don't know what class calls this method (transform) or what it does with the return value (the byte array).

Comment: I added some new stuff i found out maybe you have a new idea or can confirm my guess.

Comment: So you’re implementing a `ClassFileTransformer`? That’s a valuable information. I just checked the behavior and while load-time transformation will result in a directly reported `VerifyError` for invalid new definitions, in case of retransformation, the error gets swallowed by the JVM and the retransformation does not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, it seems that when `Instrumentation.retransformClasses` is invoked, errors with the transformed code, like `VerifyError`, are not reported by the JVM, but instead, it will simply proceed with the old code.

I don’t see any way to change the JVM’s behavior here. It’s worth creating an additional test environment, where you use a different method to activate the code, like load-time transformation or just transforming the compiled classes statically and try to load these. This may be in addition to the production code which uses the same transformation code with `retransformClasses`, once these tests show no errors.

By the way, when you implement a `ClassFileTransformer`, you should pass the `byte[]` array you received as parameter for the `transform` method to the `ClassReader(byte[])` constructor instead of using the `ClassReader(String)` constructor.

---

Second, the code location of the last reported line number is also a branch target. Keep in mind that line breaks do not generate code, so the end of the loop is identical with the start of the `return` statement.

ASM will report the associated artifacts in the following order:

- `visitLabel` with a `Label` instance associated with the code location
- `visitLineNumber` with the new line number and the `Label` from the previous step
- `visitFrame` to report a stack map frame associated with this code location (as it is a branch target)

You are inserting a new instruction at the `visitLineNumber` call, which causes the branch target to be *before* this new instruction, as you delegated the `visitLabel` before it. But the `visitFrame` call gets delegated *after* the new instructions have been inserted, hence, is not associated with the branch target anymore. This causes a `VerifyError`, as it is mandatory to have a stackmap frame for each branch target.

A simple, but expensive solution would be, not to use the original class’ stackmap frames, but let ASM recompute them. I.e.

```
public static byte[] getTransformed(byte[] originalCode) {
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(originalCode);
    ClassVisitor tcv = new TransformClassVisitor(cw);
    cr.accept(tcv, ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);
    return cw.toByteArray();
}
```

By the way, when you keep most of the original code but only insert some new statements, it’s beneficial to optimize the process by [passing the `ClassReader` to the `ClassWriter`’s constructor](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#ClassWriter-org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader-int-):

```
public static byte[] getTransformed(byte[] originalCode) {
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(originalCode);
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
    ClassVisitor tcv = new TransformClassVisitor(cw);
    cr.accept(tcv, ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);
    return cw.toByteArray();
}
```

A more efficient solution which does not recalculate the stackmap frames (as the original frames are still suitable for such a simple transformation), is not that easy with ASM’s API. The only idea I have so far, would be to postpone the insertion of the new instruction until the frame has been visited, if there is one. Unfortunately, that implies overriding all `visit` methods for instructions:

Stay with

```
public static byte[] getTransformed(byte[] originalCode) {
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(originalCode);
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, 0);
    ClassVisitor tcv = new TransformClassVisitor(cw);
    cr.accept(tcv, 0);
    return cw.toByteArray();
}
```

and use

```
static class Transformator extends MethodVisitor {
    int lastLineNumber;

    public Transformator(MethodVisitor mv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, mv);
    }
    public void visitLineNumber(int line, Label start) {
        lastLineNumber = line;
        super.visitLineNumber(line, start);
    }
    private void checkLineNumber() {
        if(lastLineNumber > 0) {
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, classpath,"visitLine","()V", false);
            lastLineNumber = 0;
        }
    }
    public void visitTryCatchBlock(Label start, Label end, Label handler, String type) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitTryCatchBlock(start, end, handler, type);
    }
    public void visitMultiANewArrayInsn(String descriptor, int numDimensions) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitMultiANewArrayInsn(descriptor, numDimensions);
    }
    public void visitLookupSwitchInsn(Label dflt, int[] keys, Label[] labels) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitLookupSwitchInsn(dflt, keys, labels);
    }
    public void visitTableSwitchInsn(int min, int max, Label dflt, Label... labels) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitTableSwitchInsn(min, max, dflt, labels);
    }
    public void visitIincInsn(int var, int increment) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitIincInsn(var, increment);
    }
    public void visitLdcInsn(Object value) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitLdcInsn(value);
    }
    public void visitJumpInsn(int opcode, Label label) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitJumpInsn(opcode, label);
    }
    public void visitInvokeDynamicInsn(
        String name, String desc, Handle bsmHandle, Object... bsmArg) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(name, desc, bsmHandle, bsmArg);
    }
    public void visitMethodInsn(
        int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc, boolean iface) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc, iface);
    }
    public void visitFieldInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name,String descriptor) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitFieldInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor);
    }
    public void visitTypeInsn(int opcode, String type) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitTypeInsn(opcode, type);
    }
    public void visitVarInsn(int opcode, int var) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitVarInsn(opcode, var);
    }
    public void visitIntInsn(int opcode, int operand) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitIntInsn(opcode, operand);
    }
    public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
        checkLineNumber();
        super.visitInsn(opcode);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, ASM’s visitor model has no `preVisitInstr()` or such alike.

Note that with this design, it is also impossible to erroneously inject instructions after the method’s last instruction as the injected instruction(s) are always placed before another instruction.

Comment: Thank you so much thats the solution i was searching for.